# Cannot get data from API for android device (React-Native)

Tags: android, react-native, api

I'm trying to get data from an API to Android, but something happened that prevents me from getting the data or results in a timeout error. I have tested this code on the following platforms:

1. Snack Expo (Web): It passed and I was able to get the data successfully.
2. Expo (localhost: web): It passed and I was able to get the data successfully.
3. Expo (Android Emulator): It failed, as it took a very long time to load and no data was received.
4. Expo GO (real Device): It failed with the error message "Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /ip".

   Version

   - "expo": "~48.0.15",
   - "react": "18.2.0",
   - "react-native": "0.71.8",

- This is my code, App.json is folowing

  **App:**

  ```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';

  export default function Test2() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = () => {
      console.log("start");
      fetch('https://646ee64209ff19b120864a07.mockapi.io/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("data:", data);
          setData(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log("end");
        });
    };

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>Id user: {item.id}</Text>
              <Text>Name user: {item.name}</Text>
              <Text>-------------------------</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  ```

**App.Json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "MyApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I Tried:

- Check Internet: good connect
- Check JSON file: pass

link of JSON I used for test: https://646ee64209ff19b120864a07.mockapi.io/users

Answer (score 1):

After 30 mins, I find the solution.
Because Expo don't have Manifest file, we will do it in another way
**Add this code to app.json:**

```
"android": {
      "config": {
        "cleartextTraffic": true
      },}
```

//Skip any part if it already exist on your file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your androidManifest.xml file

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: thanks you so much. Even Expo don't have Manifest file, I can sovle my problems by fix it in app.json

Comment: My pleasure to be of help. Please mark your answer as the correct one so others can also benefit.